# Difference between Generic, Type , wildcard in Java

Tags: java, generics

My problem is not regarding the usage but of terminology. To put simply, who is generic, Type, Wildcard among them -

```
List<T> 
List<Integer>
List<? extends Number>
```

You can add your own examples too. I understand `T` will be Type , `?` wildcard but then what is generic and what do we call `Integer` used here ?

Comment: all the three represent generic, T represent it can be of any type, and ? represent here that the list should be for some type of Number

Comment: Thanks for the super quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source of information would be the Oracle tutorials, like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html):

```
public interface List <E> {
  void add(E x);
  Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

*Those are the declarations of the formal type parameters of the interfaces List and Iterator.*

But of course, the ultimate answers can be found in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), like:

*A class is generic if it declares one or more type variables*

Or further down:

*A method is generic if it declares one or more type variables*

In other words: to really understand **terminology**, start reading the JLS, sections 8.1.2 and 8.4.4.

Beyond that: a more human readable but still in-depth introduction is the FAQ by [Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).